# MessageBox in canDeactivate method throws error in Firefox 25.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, durandal

This fails in Firefox  25.0 but works without problems in Chrome and IE 11:

```
 var canDeactivate = function () {
    if (hasChanges()) {
        console.log(customer().CustomerID() < 0);
        var msg = customer().CustomerID() < 0 ?
            'Are you sure you want to discard the customer - "' + customer().CustomerName() + '" ?' :
            'Are you sure you want to discard the changes\n for the the customer - "' + customer().CustomerName() + '" ?';
        var title = 'Confirm navigation';
        return app.showMessage(msg, title, ['Yes', 'No'])
            .then(confirmDelete);

        function confirmDelete(selectedOption) {
            if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

In Firefox  25.0 it throws a ReferenceError before it evaluates the response from the message box and it is canceling the navigation without calling the function `confirmDelete`.

What is the problem?

Comment: What Version of Firefox are you using

Comment: Firefox ver 25.0. I updated the question.

Comment: wondering if you have to define confirmDelete before app.showMessage call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the `function confirmDelete() {...}` before the return statement solved the problem.